# Laravel/ui package doesn't work after pulled from github

Tags: laravel

so my friend and i are working on a project and we install laravel/ui package on his device to use Auth:routes, but after i pull from github it says "In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package." even though i also pulled all file that he push and the gitignore file is empty. does this mean i have to install laravel/ui package in my device too? because i dont want to have the client to installed all those again when we finished and send the folder to our client. we used laravel 7.24 btw

Comment: Regenerate the classes `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: on my device or my friend's?

Comment: so i did it on my device and it work, thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to regenerate the classes as :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

you should open the terminal on your project root directory and  run :

```
composer install
```

on your system.because probably the vendor directory(where the packages are located) added to `.gitignore`
if vendor not added in `.gitignore` try to run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: i run `composer dump-autoload` on my device and it work, so would you mind explain what's `composer install` do? because the gitignore is empty

Comment: composer is a dependency manager for PHP. read about that